# Use SQL without implementing a new SQL table in the program

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

There is a lot of tutorials out there showing me how to create a new table and ammend the data. But will creating a new table every time overwrite my existing table?

Once the table has been created and the rows of data have been added, I wouldn't need my program to create a new table again. Just read and ammend from it.

I don't want the user to create a table, so I just want the table to already be there before I even run my program.

I figured I could use run something like this to create my database tables once:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-database.htm

Run it! And then once it is created, use this next guide to connect to where I stored it in the actual program.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-select-database.htm

Be nice to find a tutorial on how to just manually make the database parameters outside of code.

The project is for university, they want me to create a client similar to MySpace. Have clients connect to a server, share music and message friends. I have done the UI and multi threaded server connections and understand how to read and write data to the UI or File. Just figured an SQL database would be the best way to store all this user data.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to check the table Exist or not.

If the table exist then use it else create it and then you can use it.